# PHP and Creating Directories

Tags: php, html, ftp, directory, server

Quick question. I'll start off with an example.

I have a social site similar to Facebook. When a user signs up my PHP script creates a directory named after his username and a custom sub-directory for this user called "photos".

The "photos" directory is never created when someone signs up. I assume it is because the actual server hasn't created the actual username directory in the first place.

My solution is that anytime i need to execute the photo function on my site for a user I should check if the folder exists and if not create it, which works fine. Is this standard procedure? Or is there a better way to create multiple directories at the same time while running checks.

When someone signs up I run this code, and the latter if statement doesn't successfully create the photos folder, so i check these two statements anytime I am editing something that would go in photos as a check for if the folder exists.

```
if (!file_exists("user/$username")) {
    mkdir("user/$username", 0755);
}
if (!file_exists("user/$username/photos"))
{
    mkdir("user/$username/photos", 0755);
}
```

Comment: Yes you can, but you will need to share some code in order to get help

Comment: i edited some code in, seems trivial so didn't think to add it initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directories are created sequentially/synchronously thus once execution of the first `mkdir()` is finished the folder should be there with the indicated permission set.

As stated [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) the `mkdir()`

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

and

> Emits an E_WARNING level error if the directory already exists.
>
> Emits an E_WARNING level error if the relevant permissions prevent
>   creating the directory.

So you can go:

```
if (!file_exists("user/$username")) {
    if(mkdir("user/$username", 0755))
    {
        //directory created
        if (!file_exists("user/$u/photos"))
        {
            mkdir("user/$username/photos", 0755);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //directory not created
    }
}
```

If the `mkdir()` returns `false` - check the logs or handle the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a quick directory 'exists' check like this

```
   function check($images_dir) {
        if($handle = opendir($images_dir)) {
            // directory exists do your thing

               closedir($handle);
            } else {
             // create directory
           }                
        }
```

Where `$images_dir` = path/directory/user/$username